# How to get 64 bit Windows desktop app to read the wow6432node

Tags: windows-7, windows-registry, installer

I installed a windows desktop application. The  installer is Inno Setup and it put my license key for the app under the wow6432node. But when I start the app  it tells me it cannot find the license. Can I do anything to get the app to find the license?

Comment: Unless this is a 32-bit application it won’t be able to read that key

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's nothing *you* can do to make the app work.

What should happen is that the app developer, if he knows the license will always be in the 32-bit registry, needs to alter his call to **RegOpenKeyEx** from

```
RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, ...);
```

to

```
RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_CURRENT_USER | KEY_WOW64_32KEY, ...);
```

Or the 32-bit installer needs to put the license information in the 64-bit registry, by changing:

```
RegOpenKeyEx(HEKY_CURRENT_USER, ...)
```

to

```
RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_CURRENT_USER | KEY_WOW64_64KEY, ...);
```

Since neither of those things is in your control; you should simply copy the license information from the 32-bit registry to the 64-bit registry yourself using RegEdit.

Comment: Superuser readers aren't deeply familiar with Win32 APIs and or-ed flags. Add some old school explanations so that general readers can understand ;)

Comment: @Biswapriyo Really the first sentence answers it; and mirrors what you said.

Comment: @Biswapriyo - If a reader isn't familiar with Win32 APIs then it's up to them to learn.  This answer is correct.  I don't see any way to make more people understand it.  Subject matter knowlege is required in a case like this.